# Is there any jquery plugin to capture both image and video from webcam like the one in Facebook wall system?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is javascript the only way to access any webcam to capture image and video while the scripting language is php?

Is there any jquery plugin to capture both image and video from webcam like the one in  Facebook wall system? I searched but could not find one to satisfy both needs.

The scripting langauge I'll be using is php.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook style video embed plugin for jQuery
http://ajaxdump.com/2011/04/26/facebook-style-video-embed-plugin-for-jquery/

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question thought you needed a plugin to embed videos with an image. This is a jquery webcam plugin http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ i'm sure you can combine them or with other plugins to get the affect you want.